# Printing python modulus operator as it is over command line

Tags: python, operators, modulo

I want to print modulus operator as it is over the command line:
E.g this is how the output should look like:
1%2
2%4

or
30%
40%

I am using the print statement like this:

> print 'computing %s % %s' % (num1,
>   num2)

Its throwing the default error:

> TypeError: not all arguments
>   converted during string formatting

For now I am using:

> print 'computing 1'+'%'+'2'

which prints:

> computing 1%2

But tell me how to get this done using the first approach(:print 'computing %s % %s' % (num1,num2))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape the % sign with another % sign, like this:

```
print 'computing %s %% %s' % (num1, num2)
```

Comment: Documentation Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 1):

```
print 'computing %s %% %s' % (num1, num2)
```